# Select pdf urls with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to select urls with pdf file extension and list the pdfs separately, using jQuery or PHP.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the selector

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']")
```

To move them:

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']").appendTo(".PDFDump");
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/opefo